# the map is incorrect

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm new to ros and i'm using a bag file and i'm following the hector slam tutorial . i can see the map using rviz but the map is not clear and it's looks incorrect
http://i57.tinypic.com/14wdjj5.png
Team_Hector_MappingBox_Dagstuhl_Neubau.bag

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197291/the-map-is-incorrect/) by [Soroosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20786/soroosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Scanmatch is not well ,

try changing `map_update_angle_thresh` value in `hector_slam / hector_mapping / launch / mapping_default.launch`

```
 <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
```

default value is 0.9

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0